# Is the sentence "we grew warmer and warmer" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

I did a Google search on the the sentence, "We grew warmer and warmer," and it only came up with a few hits, not even one page worth. So is this grammatically incorrect? Is there a better way to put this?

Comment: What are you trying to say?  Context would be very helpful, as the sentence, while grammatically correct, does not make much sense.

Comment: I'm trying to make a sentence like this: "We embraced, growing warmer and warmer." Basically two people embrace each other tightly during a winter night, and their tight embrace warms each other up more and more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase works absolutely fine in the context you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It' grammatically correct. Perhaps the reason you received so few results from Google has something to do with the phrase being rather bland.